# VS 2013: how to detect the build command

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I would like to create a simple VS2013 extension that does something when the user builds his project. Just before the actual build I want to be able to do something.

How can I detect de build event?

Comment: Use BuildEvents.OnBuildBegin

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? When the build starts, what action are you going to take? I ask only because people think they want to detect a build event and don't actually want that.

Comment: I just want to create something little that increments the build number on each build.

Comment: What about command line builds?